# Word2vec from scratch: No module named 'utils_modified'

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, torch

I am trying to reproduce this code: https://github.com/n0obcoder/skip-gram-model

However I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils_modified'
```

could you please tell me what it is wrong there?

Comment: `from Skip-Gram-Model import utils_modified` include the above line

Answer (score 0):

As Subbu VidyaSekar stated in the comments, you need to import `utils_modified` from `Skip-Gram-Model`.

You first need to install `Skip-Gram-Model` in the computer terminal, then include

```
from Skip-Gram-Model import utils_modified
```

as the first line of your code.

Comment: probably I have not installed it as I have never used it. However, if I try to install it using pip install Skip-Gram-Model I get this: `Collecting Skip-Gram-Model
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Skip-Gram-Model (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Skip-Gram-Model`